# XML Comments in source code for derived classes or interface implementations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

Related to my previous question. If I define an interface I'll comment its members. I then don't comment the implementing class's implementation unless there is a reason the original comment is no longer valid.

Resharper is fine with this, Visual studio claims it's a warning.

Importantly the inherited comments are displayed through intellisense when you work with them, which is pretty much my only real concern.

What are your thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding comments to your code is always a good practice. If a component is a private or internal class, and it will be always exposed via a known interface or abstract class that has all comments in place, then you may only need to comment specific things on the implementation of that class (for example if more than one person is going to look at the code, or if you happen to return to your code after a few years). That way it will be easier to understand what the code does and why. If you have enabled XML documentation to be generated when you build the project, Visual Studio will warn you for undocumented members.

I am also receiving Resharper warnings on some classes when I enable the XML documentation generation, but Resharper warns only for items with public visibility. 
To shorten the documentation work, I'd recommend commenting public classes and interfaces first (especially if you are releasing a product library), and if there is enough time, the internal/private ones. If you decide not to comment the latter, just make sure you or anyone who will be working with the code will easily understand the logic and the reasons behind it.

Comment: I'm fine with what I need to document, it was rather that Visual Studio didn't agree with me. Apparently the application of the warning is over zealous :/ Thanks for your take on it though.

Comment: I'm glad I was useful. I hope I wasn't too abusive with the comment advices on various pieces of code, just wanted to make sure you don't repeat a mistake I did some time ago. Generally, one should make a difference between code comments and documentation comments, but I didn't want to appear as advising you not to put comments at all.

Comment: Your answer was good, not abusive at all. Commenting is one of those fun topics that can end up in holy war territory which is always fun :) Anyway, personally I prefer answers with too much information, that assume my level of knowledge is lower, than ones that provide too little information. I always assume someone else will read it too and get value from it :)

Comment: @Ian, yes, I agree. I personally learned a lot from other people's questions from this site and not only. Actually some little pieces of information not directly related to a question and answer have made me ask a question here to better clarify my understandings. I also like that way of thinking - perceiving 'holy war' topics as fun and as a source of knowledge, rather than loosing one's self in endless arguing :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same "issue", and I think Visual Studio is properly reporting a code smell.

Your issue, if I understand correctly, is that it isn't [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to have what amount to the same comments on your interface and on your implementation. That makes a lot of sense -- much of the time, especially when you're mocking and testing, code is going to use the interface, not the implementation, when you have one. Why duplicate?

Well, I bet your class is marked `public`. If that's the case, ***the class CAN be used without the interface by outside code***. Those external users deserve some comments, and you never know when you have extra public methods that aren't captured in the list of interfaces you're implementing. Comment it up!

If you don't want to make these comments, however (at least in VS 2017; I realize you were using 2013, which I don't have handy), ***you can mark the implementing class `internal` and skip the comments***.

And then your unDRY comment problem is solved.